# Graphing margin of error and sample size required in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a chart relating margin of error and sample size required. But something beyond my skills is going wrong. Does anyone knows how I can fix it?

```
 # range of margin of error
alpha=seq(0.01, 0.10, by=.01)
nalpha <- length(alpha)

# sample sizes
samps =seq(0, 15000, by=500)[-1]
nsamps <- length(samps)

# obtain sample sizes vs MoE
samsize <- array(numeric(nalpha*nsamps), dim=c(nalpha,nsamps))
for (i in 1:nsamps){
  for (j in 1:nalpha){
    result = sqrt( (.5*(1-.5))/samps) * qnorm(1-alpha/2)
    samsize[j,i] <- result[j]
  }
}

# graphing
x <- range(alpha)
y <- round(range(nsamps))
cols <- rainbow(length(samps))

plot(x, y, type="n",
     ylab="Sample Size (n)",
     xlab="Margin of Error" )

# add power curves
for (i in 1:nsamps){
  lines(alpha, samsize[,i], type="l", lwd=2, col=cols[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your value of `y` in the `plot()`

```
y
# [1] 30 30
```

but then you are using the values of `samsize` as the `y` values in lines.

```
range(samsize)
# [1] 0.01163087 0.05759729
```

That's way outside the range you've defined for the plot so those values will never show up. I'm not sure exactly what you intended to plot, but you'll want to make sure the values for `y` you use in `plot()` and `lines()` match up in order to actually see the lines.